# HTML5 video player on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, html, safari, mobile-safari

Does the HTML5 video player on the iPad Safari have the capability to play equivalent Flash content ?

Since the iPad does not have Flash support, is there any way by which the same content can be converted into an HTML5 format (something which can be played on the iPad) ? If yes, does HTML5 support creation of highly complex Flash like content ?

Comment: If you are able to send h.264 encoded mpeg4/mov(and few other formats) content to the webview/movie player it can be played easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty good article on the topic as far as video is concerned: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/video.html

If you are looking for a solution for interactive content have a look at http://swiffy.googlelabs.com/

Comment: Thx a lot for that...Could you please suggest something which is specific to iPad ?

Comment: If you want something iPad-specific just build an iPad-App?

Comment: I am looking at a web app, which would be able to play Flash like content (though of course not swf) in an HTML5 player on Safari..

Comment: Well there's a gazillion ways of doing sth like this (almost). It's hard to tell what exactly is "Flash-like". Do you want lots of animation or do you lots of want "interactivity" or both or lots of video or something else? Hard to tell. Probably HTML5 + JavaScript is the aprroximate way to go, but I guess you'll have to carve out what you really need beforehand and then find the appropriate solutions in Non-Flash environments.

Comment: When I say Flash-like content, it includes both complex animations as well as advanced functionalities that are used in Flash...I am looking at ways by which those can also work on the iPad..

Answer (score 2):

I see this as two questions:

*Since the iPad does not have Flash support, is there any way by which the same content can be converted into an HTML5 format (something which can be played on the iPad) ?*

By the same token that you can take a video and convert it to .flv format, you can (and will need to) convert the video to mp4/m4v/h.264 codec format. A tutorial for converting a video to h.264 with Handbrake is found here: http://www.simplewebtv.com/en_tutorials.html?doc=video_handbrake

Please note that your server may need to have the filetype identified to properly serve video.  A quick description of adding Mime types to Apache is found here: http://bignosebird.com/apache/a1.shtml

*If yes, does HTML5 support creation of highly complex Flash like content ?*

Yes, you can do much of what can be done with Flash with HTML5. To see great examples of all the things currently being done with HTML5 (using mostly `<Canvas>`), see:

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/#canvas
- http://aerotwist.com/lab/
- http://www.canvasdemos.com/

Answer (score 0):

Flash plays MP4 video files.

HTML5 video can also play MP4 video files (except on Firefox which requires WebM or Ogg).

So basically the answer is: Yes.